# Simple MYSQL in Android studio not working (Create database)

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, database-connection

So I'm making an application in Android studio and it's a very simple MYSQL application which has a window where you put in your info, and it saves it to the database. However, whenever I press done button, nothing happens. Can anyone observe where am I possible going wrong?

This is the main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText edittime, editdesc, editiniti;
Button buttonadd;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    edittime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_time);
    editdesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_desc);
    editiniti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_initi);
    buttonadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonadddata);




}
public void AddData(){
    buttonadd.setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                 boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData (editdesc.getText().toString(),
                  editiniti.getText().toString());
                  if (isInserted = true)
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  else
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
          }

    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
 as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
 int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

This is the database helper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Tasks.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tasks_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "TIME";
public static final String COL_3 = "Desc";
public static final String COL_4 = "initi";
public boolean insertData;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIME TIME, Desc TEXT, initi TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String Desc, String initi) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COL_3, Desc);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, initi);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;



}
```

}

I don't think the XML files are necessary but if they are, I'll post them up here.

Comment: You are not using mysql but sqlite, try some simple debuging (System.out.println) or use IDE to debug..., check for errors and update your question

Answer (score 0):

my friend. SQLiteOpenHelper  and MySQL are 2 different things...

if you want to use SQLIte I recommend you http://greendao-orm.com/
if you want to use MYSQL, you have to do this on the "server" part, and serve things though an API...

Comment: i just doubled checked the video it says SQLIte, so what the greendao says is that it does everything for you ?

Comment: yes, greendao does everything. it goes into your head, find out what you want to do, and magically types the code into your project.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a local database that lies inside of your Android device. To write on external database your best bet would be creating a small web service.

Answer (score 0):

This because the button has no event listener attached to it. You have to call AddData() method inside the onCreate(..) method because it is AddData() method that attaches event listener to the button.